# split string because of eslint error

Tags: javascript, eslint

i have this string:

```
`${this.new_post.type_to_send}-${this.new_post.france_service}-${this.new_post.service_web}`
```

i'm receiving an eslint error `exceeds the maximum line length of...`

I would like split this string in severals lines.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use line feeds with the template literal, but those line feeds would show up in your string. So split it to multiple lines and use string concatenation.

```
const str = `${this.new_post.type_to_send}-` + 
            `${this.new_post.france_service}-` +
            `${this.new_post.service_web}`
```

or use an array with join

```
const str = [this.new_post.type_to_send, 
            this.new_post.france_service,
            this.new_post.service_web].join('-')
```

or if you line length is not too short, use a variable to get rid of the repeated nested code.

```
const p = this.new_post
const str = `${p.type_to_send}-${p.france_service}-${p.service_web}`
```